# oracle selecting values which have same one columng but diffrent other

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this values in table :

[image: table values]

I  need to select identical ID's where VALUE is all W :
ID ; 
example ID: 534103

Answer (score 0):

Use `not exists` :

```
select distinct t.id
from table t
where not exists (select 1 from table where id = t.id and value != 'W');
```

However, you may also use `GROUP BY`

```
select id
from table t
group by id
having sum(case when value != 'W' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```

**Edit:**

```
select id
from table t
where value in ('W', 'L')
group by id
having count(distinct value) = 1;
```

Comment: But if in one ID there are L and W how can i select that ID ?

Comment: @civesuas_sine... Then use only `GROUP BY` with `where` clause. Check edited.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
select id
from t
group by id
having min(value) = max(value) and min(value) = 'W';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT ID
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT( CASE value WHEN 'W' THEN 1 END ) = COUNT(*)
```

or:

```
SELECT ID
FROM   your_table
GROUP BY ID
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN value = 'W' THEN NULL ELSE 1 END ) = 0
```

or, if you want all the rows for the groups that match:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         COUNT( CASE WHEN value < > 'W' THEN 1 END ) OVER ( PARTITION BY id )
           AS Num_Non_W
  FROM   your_table
)
WHERE  Num_Non_W = 0
```

Comment: But if in one ID there are W and L it will not select that record.
I need to select where value is W in the same ID or if there is one L in the same ID

Comment: @civesuas_sine That is a completely different question to the one you've have asked in the question.

Comment: Then it is.. How will I select those ID s ?